# How to cut non-circular holes in shapes?

Tags: modifiers

Climbing my Blender learning curve steadily. Trying to model this structure. [image: object to model]

In the top there's a circular cut. I was able to do that with cylinder and boolean modifier. For the bottom cut I created a shape from a cube, scaled down one side and used Ctrl+B to bevel the sides to halfround. That shape exactly was the shape that I wanted to cut out with Boolean modifier. But although it worked with the cylinder, the cut out did not work with the other shape. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Booleans can be a bit tricky - sometimes moving your "cutter" mesh _very_ slightly one direction or the other (think 0.001 units) can be enough to make it work. In the boolean modifier settings, there are "solver" options - try playing with them (mainly between fast/exact). Lastly, booleans work best if the mesh being "cut" is adequately subdivided, so blender has a good amount of vertices to choose from when calculating the post-boolean mesh topology.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can you share a blend file with just the object you're trying to cut and the cutter? It's hard to tell what went wrong otherwise. ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Answer (score 2):

Don't use boolean for this kind of object, it will generate a bad topology that you'll need to rework. Instead create a cicle, duplicate 2 of its opposite vertices, move and scale down its half:

[image]

Extrude outwards:

[image]

Flatten the edges on X and Y:

[image]

Etc:

[image]

Comment: If you use a non-destructive Boolean workflow you can easily make such cuts with Booleans.  They only become a problem when you decide to apply the Booleans.

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been very helpful.

Comment: Just one more question. Extrude outward, figured it out. Flatten edges on X and Y also. But how do I get from there to Etc.? That seems a mesh that has been changed a lot. If you can give a hint, it would be appreciated.

Comment: at what step are you stuck exactly? It would be a bit too long to explain the whole process, I mainly use extrusions (E), loopcuts (Ctrl R), join vertices (J), etc  ;)

Comment: If I look at the edges on the figure 'Flatten the edges on X and Y', and then the next picture 'Etc.' the mesh has changed quite a lot. Just a hint would help to figure that out.

Comment: I'm afraid it would be a bit too long to explain in a format like Blender Stack Exchange, maybe, if you struggle with modelling, follow some basic tutorials like Grant Abbitt's or others?

Comment: Thanks, I will take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Followed a slighty different process. This is the result.

[image]

Comment: Please describe your slightly different process so that people who find this in the future will be able to use it.